# Number Format Exception "Invalid Double"

Tags: android

I have to build a calculator and i am making some validations, the code is kinda long so i will only put the part that is breaking it.

It is a validation that makes the multiplication, it breaks when trying to multiply a negative number, every other operation is done correctly but the multiplication:

```
else if(resulttxt.getText().toString().contains("*")){

                String resultarray=resulttxt.getText().toString();
                String[] split=resultarray.split("\\*");
                finalresult = Double.valueOf(split[0]) * Double.valueOf(split[1]);

                if (finalresult<0){
                    negative=true;
                }else{
                    negative=false;
                }
                resulttxt.setText(String.valueOf(finalresult));
```

resulttxt is received from a TextView that gets it's data from cliking on the numbers or the signs which are also TextViews (not buttons but they do have the On click listener)the operation is done when ciclking on the = sign.

This throws an error if for example i try to do -6*45:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "6*45"
```

Like i said everything works with the addition,substraction and division it is only the multiplication that breaks.

Comment: try  `Double.parseDouble(...)` and try `.split("*")`

Comment: What are the values of `resultarray` and `split`? I have a feeling your `split("\\*")` call isn't behaving, even though it looks like it should work. If `split` only has a length of 1, this would also confirm it.

Comment: resultarray gets it's value from resulttxt which is a TextView like i said. split is an array of strings that gets it's value from resultarray when it's split.

Comment: And type of `finalresult`?

Comment: Tried parse double with the same result. And when changing from ("\\*") to ("*") i got:      java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1:
                                                                                        *

Comment: @Hagogs I'm aware of that. I meant the *actual values* that those variables contain when you run that bit of code (either via breakpoints or logging)

Comment: finalresult is a double

Comment: unrelated, but instead of the inner `if` you can use `negative = finalresult < 0;`

Comment: Ah, well, when i use the debug option and i enter 6*6 : resultarray "6*6" then split gets done and it's value is split: {"6","6"] then split [0] which is 6 and split[1] which is 6 too get multiplied and finalresult gets a value of 36. The problem is i can´t see the values og -6*6 for example because it breaks...

Comment: Are you sure the error is really thrown in the code you have shown? It seems it comes from the place where you handle the unary -.

Comment: I'm presuming in that case you've got a previous `else if` statement for minus `-`? Is the code falling into that statement instead?

Comment: Hint: the stack trace shows the file and line number where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Check log result for `resultarray`

Comment: Going to check that.

Comment: I just added the answer to the problem... ty for suggesting to check logcat, i didn't knew it actually points you to the line where the exception occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG dudes... this is what was the problem:

I had this validation at the end of the other operations, so BEFORE even going to the multiplication part it entered the "-" validation when it checks

```
if(resulttxt.contains("-")){
```

because it is a negative value so it does have a "-"... so it entered as a substraction instead as a multiplication because of that...

To solve it i had to put the substraction validation at the bottom of all of them.

So thank you for the guys who suggested me to check the line where the error was thrown i wouldn't have known logcat actually tells you were the mistake is and to my surprise it was on the substraction validation which to me was a "WTF" moment and then i realized what i just told you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried executing your code in the compiler :

```
String resulttxt = "-6*45";
     boolean negative = false;
     if(resulttxt.contains("*")){

            String resultarray=resulttxt;
            String[] split=resultarray.split("\\*");
            double finalresult = Double.valueOf(split[0]) * Double.valueOf(split[1]);

            if (finalresult<0){
                negative=true;
            }else{
                negative=false;
            }
    System.out.println(finalresult);
     }
```

Every thing worked fine for, please verify datatype used in your program.

addition, multiplication and division works fine. "-6+45, -6*45 and -6/45"(any other combination. I just used the same)

However for subtraction as the pattern is "-6-45" the above logic will fail and throw number format exception. This is because if you split "\-", the "-" is first character in string and there is nothing before it.

Thus your split will fail. So to avoid this you can always take last index of character to split using substring function.

Comment: Yeah, for substraction i have an additional validation which removes the first ("-") then splits using the other ("-") and then when doing the actual math the first number is multiplied for -1 to recover it's original value.

Comment: It is weird because i have doublechecked and the code is the same, i just don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
 String s1 = resultarray.substring(0,resultarray.indexOf("*"));
 String s2 = resultarray.substring(resultarray.indexOf("*")+1,resultarray.length());

 double d1= Double.valueOf(s1);
 double d2= Double.valueOf(s2);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry if this is an stupid question but what is "d"?